# Is it possible to run your app on a tablet and not the simulator in WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to test it on a tablet because it is more natural to test than by using a simulator but I don't know if that is possible?

It is written in C# & XAML in Windows 8 RP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never tried personally but this would be my start: 
[Debugging Metro Apps on Remote Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh441469(v=vs.110))

[image: Remote Machine option in VS]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Remote Debugging tools. :-)